# Parse Nested XML with xDocument

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have an XML format of this structure (the real world example is horrendously long and complicated, but this should illustrate it):

```
<document>    <post>
      <author>Bill Smith</author>
      <subject>Test Article</subject>
      <dates>
          <uploaded>some date</uploaded>
          <published>some date</published>
      </dates>
    </post>
    <post>
      <author>Bill Smith</author>
      <subject>Test Article</subject>
      <dates>
          <uploaded>some date</uploaded>
          <published>some date</published>
      </dates>
    </post>  </document>
```

I have wrote a simple query to pull out each of the posts. I can get the author and subject fine, but I don't know how to drill down into the dates part to pull out the published bit.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following LINQ to get the first "published" element.

```
    XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"D:\XMLFile1.xml", LoadOptions.None);
    XElement element = document
    .Descendants("document")
            .Descendants("post")
    .Descendants("dates")
    .Descendants("published")
    .First();
string publishedDate = element.Value;
```

You can give any expressions as parameter to the 'Descendants' method.
If you have xml as a string, you can use the following to read it into an `XDocument`

```
XDocument.Parse();
```

Please remember to check for nulls!! :-)

Comment: Thanks James, I did figure it out in the end myself. I didn't realise at first that you could chain .Descendants() like that.

Comment: @MartinAlderson In case you have not noticed yet, If there are no elements on that path to return 'First()' will throw an error, in that case it might be better to use 'FirstOrDefault()'.