# Reading and analysing XML string

Tags: c#, xml

Please can someone help me work out how to analyse the following XML:

```
<staff name="peter">
  <staff name="martin">
     <staff name="mike" />
  </staff>

  <staff name="stuart" />
</staff>
```

How do I reference the values in the "" ?
Basically I want to return all staff where their name starts with a particular letter e.g 'm'

Comment: [How to: Find Elements with a Specific Attribute (XPath-LINQ to XML) (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-find-elements-with-a-specific-attribute-xpath-linq-to-xml)

Comment: This seems very oddly constructed XML, is it a cut down version of a bigger file.

Comment: Its an from an Api return

Comment: I could be wrong, but it seems like this XML might have an error. the staff member martin doesn't have a close tag, and the close tag at the end does not belong to any member

Comment: Its an org chart structure.
Peter is the CEO (relates to the end close tag)
Under him you have Martin and Stuart.
Under Martin, you have Mike

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided any code which you have tried, i can guide you a bit.

1. Use `XDocument` to help you with the parsing
2. Use the `Descendants` method (chain it) to locate your node/element
3. Call something like `First()` to get your desired data

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126644/parse-nested-xml-with-xdocument/15126999#15126999) answer for a small example about the usage of `XDocument` and `Descendants`
Hope this helps

Comment: To be honest, This is not something I have done before, just something I have been asked to look at. I have googled and tried different things which don't really give me what I want.

Comment: @Richard.Gale I have updated the answer with a link to an example for you.

Answer (score 0):

use this reference to read your xml file into an object.

```
    public static T DeserializeXMLFileToObject<T>(string XmlFilename)
{
    T returnObject = default(T);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(XmlFilename)) return default(T);

    try
    {
        StreamReader xmlStream = new StreamReader(XmlFilename);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        returnObject = (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlStream);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionLogger.WriteExceptionToConsole(ex, DateTime.Now);
    }
    return returnObject;
}
```

You call the this method using something like this:

```
MyObjType MyObj = DeserializeXMLFileToObject<MyObjType>(FilePath);
```

once you have the objects:

```
for(int i = 0; i < StaffMemebers.length; i++)
{
     NamesStartingWithLetter(StaffMemebers[i],'A',ref NameList);
}

public void NamesStartingWithLetter(StaffObject staffMember,char letter,ref List<string> NamesFound)
{
     if(staffMember.Name[0]==letter)
          NamesFound.Add(staffMember.Name);
     if(staffMember.staff!=null)
          NamesStartingWithLetter(staffMember.staff, letter, ref NamesFound);

}
```